# Can a research statement contain research interests which are not concrete?

Tags: research-process, application, postdocs

I am applying for postdoc in physics this year. Every place asks for a statement of research or research plan/proposal for the application procedure. I have been recently following papers on a very interesting topic of research. Although I have no concrete problem/question in mind. I cannot resist myself from mentioning this topic of interest. I was wondering if I can write something like the following in a statement of research :

"I am also very interested in X. I have been closely following the rapid progress in this direction and hope to contribute in recent future."

(I want this part to write at the end of my statement of research but these sentences don't sound nice to me at all!)

Comment: As long as there is a substantial amount of concrete things in the statement, including past, but mostly current and future work, it's no harm in including a few lines at the end about this, IMO. But it shouldn't be part of the main thing.

Answer (score 2):

If a statement does not sound right to you, it is highly likely not to sound right to other people. So you might have as well just leave it out of your statement.

Focus on what you know and what you know you are in a position to focus on as part of your further research.

If you are selected, you will have plenty of opportunities to nurture your thoughts and ideas with stimulating colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

I first want to disclose that most of my experience is in advising undergraduate students as they apply for research positions, post bacs, or graduate school -- however, similar rules would apply.

Yes, this would be appropriate as long as it is presented as exploratory research, and you are able to more precisely posit an area of interest (i.e., what you currently have is too vague).  In addition, make sure that the rest of your research statement concisely summarizes your current work, and how you would like to expand on this work in their institution.  You want to be careful not to come off as "wishy-washy".  It is okay to state that you are interested in expanding your research interests (this suggests flexibility and potential for growth), as long as you highlight your current strengths and a dedication to, first and foremost, furthering the field's knowledge in your current areas of expertise.